# Jquery - use the same function for multiple requests

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, button, load

I have this CLICK function that works for one specific HTML button. I'd like to use it on multiple buttons, but each button needs to pass different variables to the same page.

**BUTTON**

```
<input type="button" id="scs" value="TEST" />
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#scs").click(function() {
    $("#status").html("<p>Please Wait! TESTING</p>");
$.ajax({
  url: 'go.php?ab=1',
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
  alert (data);
}
});
});
```

How can I adapt this so if I have 4 more buttons each button uses the function, calls the same page but uses unique values ?

EG :

```
<input type="button" id="update" value="update" /> Calls go.php?up=1
<input type="button" id="new" value="new" />  Calls go.php?new=1
```

etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your buttons the same class and call the code using the class name, and add a data attribute to each button to retrieve the seperate values.

Give this a try:

```
<input type="button" class="clickButton" data-value="go.php?up=1" value="Update" />
<input type="button" class="clickButton" data-value="go.php?new=1" value="New" />

$(".clickButton").click(function() {
    $("#status").html("<p>Please Wait! TESTING</p>");

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("data-value"),
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert (data);
            $(this).prop('value', 'New Text');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks - I like this solution as it gives me the option to add new buttons calling different pages.  One question - Is it possible to update the relevant buttons text following success ? I know how to do a specific button, but not like this.. thx

Comment: Try adding $(this).prop('value', 'New Text') into the success function. I've updated the answer to include this. If you wanted to have different 'New Text' for each button, add another attribute like the one we use for a URL and use that :)

Comment: Thanks - I had tried that and have tried it again, but it doesn't update the text on the button.

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using? If you're using a version older than 1.6 try: $(this).attr('value', 'New Text'), or if that doesn't work try: $(this).val('New Text')

Comment: latest jquery for testing. Still not updating the button text !

Comment: Hmm, not sure at the moment I'll be honest. Might be best to raise a separate question for changing a button's value on AJAX success.

Comment: Thanks got this working by adding an ID to the button and then using : `var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#' + currentId).prop('value', 'New Text');` thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the data-attribute to to set the url.
Use event delegation to target the buttons

```
<input type="button" class='btn' data-params='up=1' value="update" /> Calls go.php?up=1
<input type="button" class='btn' data-params='new=1' value="new" />  Calls go.php?new=1

$("button").on('click', '.btn', function() {
    var url = 'go.php?' + $(this).data('params');
    $("#status").html("<p>Please Wait! TESTING</p>");
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert (data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class for click event and new attribute to find the button like 'data-id'

`<input type="button" class="clickevent" data-id="update" value="update" />`

**Jquery**

`

```
$(".clickevent").click(function() {
    $("#status").html("<p>Please Wait! TESTING</p>");
$.ajax({
  url: $(this).attr('data-id'),
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
  alert (data);
}
});
});
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can check by the value of the clicked button and use a 'url' variable for the ajax request:

```
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("#status").html("<p>Please Wait! TESTING</p>");
        var url='';
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value == 'update'){
          url='go.php?up=1';
        } else if(value=='new') {
          url='go.php?new=1';
        } else if(value=='scs') {
          url='go.php?ab=1';
        }
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
      alert (data);
    }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use same class for each button

```
<input type="button" id="update" class="click" value="update" /> 
<input type="button" id="new" class="click" value="new" />

$(document).ready(function(){
               $(".click").click(function(){
                  var val=$(this).val();
                  if(val =="update")
                      {
                          $.post("go.php",{'up':'1'},function(data){
                              alert(data);
                          });
                      }
                      else
                          {
                              $.post("go.php",{'new':'1'},function(data){
                              alert(data);
                          });
                          }

               }); 
            });
```